# Email Is not sending successfully from Asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am trying to send Email from My asp.net web application which i have developed only for practice purpose but it is not working at all i tried so many things, so many times from google and youtube also but it is not working at all. please do help me if possible.....

one more thing i am doing it in college campus and their firewall is on so i tried it from another network also still it is not working...???

```
  public bool sendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        var message = new MailMessage();
        try
        {
            message.To.Clear();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

            message.From = new MailAddress(from);

            message.Subject = subject;

            message.Body = body;

            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {


                var credential = new NetworkCredential
               {
                   UserName = "Email@mail.com",  
                   Password = "password"  
               };
               smtp.Credentials = credential;
               smtp.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;

                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(message);


            }
            flag = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: I tried for the Gmail also still it is not working
also tried by changing port 587 to 465 but still not working.

Comment: Can anybody please help me Its needed...!